# Show product only if it's related

Tags: magento2, visibility

I need to **hide** **a product** from catalog and search.

So on my product page in visibility I set `No visible individually`, but I need to show it if it is related to another product and this other product is bought.

So I **only** need to display it in **checkout/cart**.

How do I do?

**EDIT**

If it's not possible, how can I ask the user if he wants to add another product (still for cross selling) after he has added a product on his cart (but the product doesn't have to appear on the catalog nor research result)

Comment: what you mean  by ` it is related to another product ` other prooduct`?

Comment: I don't need to show the product on my catalog or in research. I have 2 products, where the second is related (for cross selling or something like that) to the first. I need to show the second on checkout/cart